# Visible spaces with multiple gets on one line

Tags: ruby, string, line, space, gets

I'm using Ruby, trying to make an interactive program. (Very new to this, I'm actually learning right now.)

Right now I have

```
puts 'Can I have your name please?
first = gets.chomp
puts 'Ok, so your first name is ' + first + '? How about your middle name?'
middle = gets.chomp
puts 'ok, so your middle name is ' + middle + '. And your last name?'
last = gets.chomp
puts 'ok, so your last name is ' + last + '?'
puts 'So your full name is ' + first + middle + last + '? That's a very nice name!
```

'

So far everything works but that last line. When the last line pops up it puts all 3 of the names together with no spaces in between. I've tried a combination of adding or deleting + or adding or deleting spaces or even '   However, nothing I do seems to work, it just stays the same. So how do I get some spaces in between my first middle and last name in that last line?

Thanks in advance for your help.... -John

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
puts "So your full name is #{first} #{middle} #{last}? That's a very nice name!"
```

This is called [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried something and managed to figure it out :D  puts 'so your full name is ' + first + ' ' + middle + ' ' + last + '.'     Worked like a charm.

Comment: @JohnnyBoy: that's a way too, but interpolation is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
[first, middle, last].join " "
```

Comment: Oh, that's way cleaner. Thanks for the advice! :D